Сериализация и десерриализация ArrayList с помощью Jackson XML
У меня проблема в следующем , есть XML :
<ds:Transforms>
   <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped"/>
   <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC"/>
</ds:Transforms>

Тег Transforms пустой, но у него есть аттрибут.
Pojo Transforms:
@Data
public class Transforms {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Transform")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper
    private List<Transform> transform;
}

Pojo Transform:
@Data
public class Transform {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "Algorithm")
    private String algorithm;
}

При сериализации и десериализации я всегда получаю :
Transforms(transform=[])

Как мне получить список Transform с атрибутами?

Этот вопрос похож на: Десериализация xml списка внутри объекта. Если вы считаете его другим, пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос, чётко обозначив отличие и/или почему ответы на вопрос не помогли в вашем случае.

и тут и там я ответил на вопрос

Поэтому это и называется дубликат -- проблема сводилась к тому, что нужно было установить useWrapping = false в обоих случаях.

Мне нужно удалить  этот вопрос? Я не совсем понимаю что я должен сделать

@Data
public class Transforms {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Transform")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    private List<Transform> transform;
}

Так сработало
